# jQuery .text() and .innerHTML not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add some text to some spans within a div pretty simple but I cannot for the life of me get this to work in IE. It works in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

heres the jQuery:

```
$("div#dateRanges #startDate").text(typeValues.dateRanges[1][0]);
$("div#dateRanges #endDate").text(typeValues.dateRanges[1][1]);
```

and heres the bit of html I'm editing:

```
<div id="dateRanges">
    <span id="startDate"></span>
    <span id="endDate"></span>
</div>
```

using jQuery to get the element and then trying to set the .innerHTMl also didn't work.

```
var startDate = $("div#dateRanges #startDate").first();
startDate.innerHTML = typeValues.dateRanges[1][0]; //Sets the text date values
var endDate = $("div#dateRanges #endDate").first();
endDate.innerHTML = typeValues.dateRanges[1][1];enter code here
```

Just to clear up potential confusion it's the setting the text of the spans I'm having trouble with. Also it may be important to include the information that this data is being updated after the page loads, through AJAX.

Comment: jQuery is guaranteed to work in all common browsers, so your first code sample should work just fine. (Or maybe you want `html()` instead.) Are you sure `typeValues.dateRanges[1][0]` contains what you think it does?

Comment: try using the developer tools in IE8 to step through your code. I've often found better debug information on IE that way.

Comment: Type values is a string of a date in the format "Month Year" And I thought that too and that's why I was amazed when this happened...

Answer (score 1):

For the second, you need to get the raw DOM element.  You can do this with `[0]` or `.get(0)`

```
var startDate = $("div#dateRanges #startDate")[0];
var endDate = $("div#dateRanges #endDate")[0];
```

Probably, `text` works, but you want it to instead be treated as HTML.  I think you can use `html` instead here:

```
$("div#dateRanges #startDate").html(typeValues.dateRanges[1][0]);
$("div#dateRanges #endDate").html(typeValues.dateRanges[1][1]);
```

Comment: var startDate = $("div#dateRanges #startDate")[0];
gives me an undefied

Comment: That just means there are no elements matching that selector.  You could try just `$("#startDate")`, if you want to match the element regardless of its ancestor.

Comment: I think Matthew Flaschen is on the right track here; your problem seems to lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

try following code, and make sure `typeValues.dateRanges` is not null.

```
var startDate = $("div#dateRanges #startDate");
startDate.html(typeValues.dateRanges[1][0]); //Sets the text date values
var endDate = $("div#dateRanges #endDate");
endDate.html(typeValues.dateRanges[1][1]); //enter code here
```

Comment: @Joshkunz:startDate.html("Hai") -> if Hai will repalce the Html of span then it will be the problem with the typeValues.dateRanges.Pls check it

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the reason for this is that jQuery's `$('#foo')` method returns an object rather than an element. There's a fascinating short write-up about it here: http://markmail.org/message/nj3iclk6jnczshop

To get around that problem, you can use the method suggested in that article, I'd imagine, but the way that I did it was to just use jQuery's `.html()` method with no arguments, as suggested by the write-up as well.